# Auto show hide value on text field depending of focus

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have text box shown bellow:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("idbox", "Enter Text here", (string)ViewBag.idbox)%>       

 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input#idbox').focus(function () {
            var txtval = $('input#idbox').val();
            if (txtval == 'Enter Text here') { $(this).val(''); }

        });
        $('input#idbox').focusout(function () {
            var txtval = $('input#idbox').val();
            if (txtval == "") { $('input#idbox').val('Enter Text here'); }
        });
    });
```

I want to make text box similar to message textarea on facebook. So if I click on text box end put some letters then value 'Enter Text here' is hide but new value don't hide if I again click on this box. That is because if statement always compare value with 'Enter text here'. How to change this code to enable me auto show-hide text value depending of focus?

Comment: So, no matter what, you want the text to clear on focus?

Comment: yes, exactly, and want it every time when click on that box. If you go to facebook and try to type message to someone you will see what I want :)

Comment: No facebook account, but why not just on focus set the value to nothing right away?

Comment: Have you looked into the HTML5 placeholder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use new `placeholder` feature instead:

```
<input type="text" name="test" value="" placeholder="Enter Text here">
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Html 5 `placeholder` property of textbox and check browser compatibilty in **http://caniuse.com/** .Because some of the old broswer will not support html 5 property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<%= Html.TextBox("idbox", (string)ViewBag.idbox, new { placeholder = "my watermark" })%>
```